# jQuery.when() progress for array of Deferred and/or Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm using jQuery's `.when()` to [wrap an array of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614377/362536) so that I can do some action when all promises have been resolved.

```
$.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
    console.log(arguments); //it is an array like object which can be looped
    var total = 0;
    $.each(arguments, function (i, data) {
        console.log(data); //data is the value returned by each of the ajax requests

        total += data[0]; //if the result of the ajax request is a int value then
    });

    console.log(total)
});
```

Suppose I wanted to be notified when each individual promise was resolved, as a way to show progress.  For instance, if `requests` has 50 requests and 3 of them are resolved, I would like to be able to display a progress bar at 6%.  Is there a way to use `$.when` so that it can return an **overall** progress without modification of the inside promises and their progress events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$.when()` doesn't do progress notifications for you.  Register for progress notifications on each individual promise or you could make your own version of `$.when()` that wraps it by first registering for done notifications on each one and then calling `$.when()`.

```
$.whenWithProgress = function(arrayOfPromises, progessCallback) {
   var cntr = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPromises.length; i++) {
       arrayOfPromises[i].done(function() {
           progressCallback(++cntr, arrayOfPromises.length);
       });
   }
   return jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises);
}

$.whenWithProgress(requests, function(cnt, total) {
    console.log("promise " + cnt + " of " + total + " finished");
}).then(function() {
    // done handler here
}, function() {
    // err handler here
});
```

---

I've been thinking about this some more and it bothered me a bit that you want progress notifications, jQuery promises have a progress mechanism and we're not using it.  That means progress notifications aren't as extensible as they could be.

Unfortunately, because `$.when()` returns a promise (not a deferred) and you can't use `.notify()` on a promise to trigger progress notifications, the above code is the simplest way to do it.  But, in the interest of using `.progress` notifications instead of a custom callback, it could be done like this:

```
$.whenWithProgress = function(arrayOfPromises) {
   var cntr = 0, defer = $.Deferred();
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPromises.length; i++) {
       arrayOfPromises[i].done(function() {
           defer.notify(++cntr, arrayOfPromises.length);
       });
   }
   // It is kind of an anti-pattern to use our own deferred and 
   // then just resolve it when the promise is resolved
   // But, we can only call .notify() on a defer so if we want to use that, 
   // we are forced to make our own deferred
   jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises).done(function() {
       defer.resolveWith(null, arguments);
   });
   return defer.promise();
}

$.whenWithProgress(requests).then(function() {
    // done handler here
}, function() {
    // err handler here
}, function(cnt, total) {
    // progress handler here
    console.log("promise " + cnt + " of " + total + " finished");
});
```

An argument against this second implementation is that the promise standards effort seems to be moving away from having progress connected to promises in any way (progress would have a separate mechanism).  But, it's in jQuery now and probably will be for a long time (jQuery does not follow the promise standards to the letter) so it's really your choice which way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that will work.  In my case, it will be `arrayOfPromises[i].done()`, but exactly the same otherwise.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brad - I added a new version that uses jQuery progress notifications.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  I was going to add that myself later, but you've done all the work for me.  Much appreciated, and great answer!

Comment: Is it a typo here: "jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises).done() {", shouldn't it be: "jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, arrayOfPromises).done(function() {" ?

Comment: @KungWaz - Yes, I fixed it.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can (or should) do this with `$.when`, whose callback is intended to only be invoked once - you want a callback that can be invoked multiple times, so you can pass it to each promise in `requests`. For example:

```
var count = requests.length;
var complete = 0;

function progress(response) {
    complete += 1;
    showProgress(complete / count);
    saveTheResponseSomewhere(response);

    if (complete === count) {
        doSomeAllDoneAction();
    }
}

requests.forEach(function(request) {
    request.then(progress);
});
```

You can add processing for actual jqXHR `progress` notifications using the third argument to `.then`. You probably also need to make sure the results are associated with the appropriate request, which might involve an extra closure in the callback.

Comment: I still want the wrap-up with `$.when()`, since I want everything to reject or resolve as one big unit in the end.  The per-request progress update is only for a progress update, not for the end status.  I think jfriend00's suggestion will work well for me, but thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping things simple, you can define a generalised classical constructor.

```
var Progress = function(promiseArray, reporter) {
    this.promiseArray = promiseArray;
    this.reporter = reporter || function(){};
    this.complete = 0;
    $.each(promiseArray, function(i, p) {
        p.then(this.increment).then(this.report);
    });
};
Progress.prototype.increment = function() {
    this.complete += 1;
};
Progress.prototype.report = function() {
    return this.reporter(this.complete, this.promiseArray.length);
};
Progress.prototype.get = function() {
    return { complete:this.complete , total:this.promiseArray.length};
};
```

Then, for eg a progress thermometer :

```
var progObj = new Progress(requests, function(complete, total) {
    var scale = 150;
    $("selector").css('someProperty', (scale * complete / total) + 'px');
});
```

Or for ad hoc enquiry :

```
console.log( progObj.get() );
```

The benefit of this approach is *reusability*. `new Progress()` could be called on any number of arrays of promises, each with its own `reporter` callback.

If you wanted, `Progress` could be made to return a jfriend-style notifiable promise, though I wouldn't do it that way for reasons jfriend has already given.

And with some more thought `Progress` could be framed as a jQuery plugin, allowing you to call, for example, as follows :

```
$("selector").progress(function(complete, total) {
    var scale = 150;
    $(this).css('someProperty', (scale * complete / total) + 'px');
});
```

which may have advantages in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Try

html

```
<progress id="progress" min="0" max="100"></progress>
<label for="progress"></label>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    var arrayOfPromises = $.map(new Array(50), function (v, k) {
        return v === undefined ? new $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
            $.post("/echo/json/", {
                json: JSON.stringify(k)
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                return dfd.notify(k).resolve([data, textStatus, jqxhr])
            });
            return dfd.promise()
        }) : null
    }),
        res = [],
        count = null;

    $.each(arrayOfPromises, function (k, v) {
        $.when(v)
            .then(function (p) {
            console.log(p[1]);
            res.push(p);
            if (res.length === arrayOfPromises.length) {
                console.log(res);
                $("label").append(" done!");
            }
        }, function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            res.push([textStatus, errorThrown, count])
        }, function (msg) {
            ++count;
            count = count;
            console.log(msg, count);
            $("progress").val(count * 2).next().text(count * 2 + "%");
        })
    })
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/0kyrdtng/

---

Previous efforts utilizing an alternative approach:

html

```
<progress id="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
<output for="progress"></output>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
            var prog = $("#progress");
            jqxhr.dfd = new $.Deferred();
            jqxhr.dfd.progress(function (data, _state) {
                prog.val(data)                    
                .siblings("output[for=progress]")
                .text(prog.val() + "% " + _state);   
                if (_state === ("resolved" || "rejected")) {
                    prog.val(100);
                    window.clearInterval(s);
                };
            });
            var count = 0.000001;
            jqxhr.counter = function (j) {
                this.dfd.notify(Math.ceil(count), this.state());
                ++count;
                console.log(this.state(), prog.prop("value"));
            };
            var s = setInterval($.proxy(jqxhr.counter, jqxhr, jqxhr), 15);
        }
    });

    $.post("/echo/json/", {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            "defer": new Array(10000)
        })
    })
    .always(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data, jqxhr.state(), $("#progress").val());
    });
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N6EgU/